# Is file modification time reliable for cache invalidation?

Tags: file, caching, cache-invalidation

I want to invalidate some locally generated cache every time file is modified.
Invalidation would happen on running manually some command-line tool (no live watch required)

My approach would be to:

1. First generate cache and store file modification date.
2. On consequent runs check if file modification date is different from the one stored - if yes: invalidate cache, and generate it again.

Is using file modification date enough for this approach to be reliable, or should I also check file shortcuts (some hash function) if file modification date hasn't changed (false positives are not a problem, but cache needs to be invalidated every time file has changed).

File will be shared using VCS and cloud storage like Dropbox or OneDrive.

Question is OS agnostic (i.e. it has to work on every commonly used operating system (Windows, Mac OS, other POSIX compliant)).

Answer (score 1):

> Is file modification time reliable for cache invalidation?

I'd say yes and I think you should consider using `Make`.

Let's say we need to cache the computation of an expensive process: counting all the numbers between 1 and *n*.

The number *n* is read from a file `input.txt`.

The file `count.cache` contains the sequence of all the numbers between 1 and *n*.

Given the following structure:

```
data/
├── input.txt
├── Makefile
```

And the following `Makefile`:

```
count.cache: input.txt
    cat $^ | xargs seq >$@
```

To start with `input.txt` is empty. Let's put some number in it:

```
echo '5'>input.txt
```

Then let's run `make`:

```
make
```

The output is as follow:

```
cat input.txt | xargs seq >count.cache
```

Here's the content of `count.cache`:

```
cat count.cache
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now let's run `make` again:

```
make
make: `count.cache' is up to date.
```

Why? In order to generate `count.cache` (the target), you need `input.txt` (the prerequisite). If the prerequisite hasn't changed then the target is still valid.

Let's update `input.txt`:

```
echo '10'>input.txt
```

And let's run `make` again:

```
make
cat input.txt | xargs seq >count.cache
```

By default `make` outputs the commands needed to generate the target. As you can see `make` has figured out that it needed to regenerate `count.cache` as its prerequisite `input.txt` has changed.

Let's verify that:

```
cat count.cache 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

---

`make` looks daunting at first sight but it is an extremely powerful tool. It's definitely worth investing time to learn it; it will pay off hundred times more!

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Comment: Does `make` rely on modification date alone internally?

Comment: As far as I know it only uses the modified date of a prerequisite to decide whether to rebuild a target. It may be using some other stuff to orchestrate its internal business but Make is a pretty old, established portable tool. So nothing fancy is required to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Redis seems the better choice for you! You can spin up an instance easily via docker and use it as a cache.

It is a new dependency but manage a lot of technicality for you